# Pass string argument to a code block from a table in org mode

Tags: python, org-mode, org-babel, org-table

I'm trying to pass a **string** as the argument of a code block when using `org-mode` and `org-babel`. In particular, I consider the following minimal example:

```
#+NAME: test
#+BEGIN_SRC python :var x="foobar"
return len(x)
#+END_SRC

| 6 | #ERROR |
#+TBLFM: @1$1='(org-sbe test)::@1$2='(org-sbe test (x ("fb")))
```

As you can note, the first cell is filled correctly. However, I cannot make the second one be processed correctly. I tried various options; for example:

```
#+TBLFM: @1$1='(org-sbe test)::@1$2='(org-sbe test (x "fb"))
#+TBLFM: @1$1='(org-sbe test)::@1$2='(org-sbe test(x="fb"))
```

Any ideas?

**BTW:** `#+CALL: test(x="fb")` returns the expected result, i.e. `2`. It seems like the syntax for inline calling or "table-calling" is different... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the right combination!

```
| 6 | 3 |
#+TBLFM: @1$1='(org-sbe test)::@1$2='(org-sbe test (x \"bar\"))
```

Note that the `"` have to be escaped...